# Size mismatch, m1: [1 x 5], m2: [7 x 100] at /pytorch/aten/src/TH/generic/THTensorMath.cpp:752

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, mlp

I am new to pytorch and trying to create a model, but I getting this error,

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-a0f31875b0ba> in <module>()
      1 for t in range(100):
      2     # Forward pass
----> 3     y_pred = model(X_train)
      4 
      5     # Accuracy


AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'dim'
```

Here is my code:

```
x = np.array([2,4,6,18,20,30,50])
y = x * 2
print(x)
print(y)


shuffle_indices = torch.LongTensor(random.sample(range(0, len(x)), 
len(x)))
x = x[shuffle_indices]
y = y[shuffle_indices]

x = torch.from_numpy(x).float()
y = torch.from_numpy(y.ravel()).long()

# Split datasets
test_start_idx = int(len(x) * 0.75)
X_train = x[:test_start_idx] 
y_train = y[:test_start_idx] 
X_test = x[test_start_idx:] 
y_test = y[test_start_idx:]
print("We have %i train samples and %i test samples." % (len(X_train), len(X_test)))
```

> We have 5 train samples and 2 test samples.

```py
class MLP(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dim, hidden_dim, output_dim):
        super(MLP, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(input_dim, hidden_dim)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(hidden_dim, output_dim)

    def forward(self, x_in, apply_softmax=False):
        a_1 = F.relu(self.fc1(x_in))
        y_pred = self.fc2(a_1)

        if apply_softmax:
            y_pred = F.softmax(y_pred, dim=1)

        return y_pred

model = MLP(input_dim=len(X_train), 
        hidden_dim=100, 
        output_dim=len(set(y)))
print (model.named_modules)
```

> bound method Module.named_modules of MLP((fc1): Linear(in_features=7, out_features=100, bias=True)
>     (fc2): Linear(in_features=100, out_features=7, bias=True)
>   )

```py
loss_fn = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=1e-3)

def get_accuracy(y_pred, y_target):
    n_correct = torch.eq(y_pred, y_target).sum().item()
    accuracy = n_correct / len(y_pred) * 100
    return accuracy

for t in range(7):
    y_pred = model(X_train)
    _, predictions = y_pred.max(dim=1)
    accuracy = get_accuracy(y_pred=predictions.long(), y_target=y_train)
    loss = loss_fn(y_pred, y_train)
    if t%20==0: 
        print ("epoch: {0} | loss: {1:.4f} | accuracy: {2:.1f}%".format(t, loss, accuracy))
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
```

Comment: Could you provide a sample of X_train and y_train?

Comment: I have updated the code for samples @zihaozhihao

Comment: Well, your `input_dim` should be `len(X_train)` instead of `len(x)`.

Comment: That's great. It solved my error. But now I ot the another one. "AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'dim'"

Comment: Could you update your current code?

Comment: you should convert numpy into tensor before feeding into your model.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `X_train` is a `numpy.ndarray` object which needs to be converted to `torch.Tensor`. So, a solution to your problem would be:

```
y_pred = model(torch.from_numpy(X_train))
```